# Evaluating first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I was given $$(x+3y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$ and also $y>0$ so I wrote it as 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x}{y} + 3y$$ now substituting $x=y.t$ and $$ \frac{dx}{dy}=t+y.\frac{dt}{dy}$$
I am finally left with
$$dt=3dy$$
Integrating which becomes
$$t=3y+c_1=x/y$$
Is this correct??

Comment: A tip is when solving the ode try putting the solution back into the equation :).

Comment: Doest seem to satisfy , whats wrong?

Comment: So you get $x=3y^2+c_1y$. If I report this into the initial equation, it works.